# How to verify an item exists in an array with objects?

Tags: php

I have an array of objects called items:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => stdClass Object 
        (   
            [id] => 1 
            [libelle_fr] => service un 
            [libelle_en] => service one 
            [prix] => 1111.222 
        ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [id] => 2 
            libelle_fr] => serivce deux 
            [libelle_en] => service tow 
            [prix] => 2222.222
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [id] => 3 
            [libelle_fr] => service trois 
            [libelle_en] => service three 
            [prix] => 333.33 
        )  
)
```

I'd like to look if the id number 5 exists in the items array, or whatever any other member of the class.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [FluentFunctions](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/fluent_functions.html) from [ouzo goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies)

```
 $result = Arrays::any($array, FluentFunctions::extractField('id')->equals(5));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop the array:

```
$input  = array(); // your input data
$exists = false;

foreach ($input as $item) {
  if ($item->id == 5) {
    $exists = true;
   break;
  }
}
```

You can also use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce):

```
$exists = array_reduce($input, function($result, $item){
  return $result || $item->id == 5;
}, false);
```

Comment: Well I know this but I look for something much esay, In .NET I just use the .where() function,So I'm asking if there is any similair solution. Thank

Comment: This will return true or the object where id = 5?

Comment: @Rad It will return an information `if the id number 5 exists in the items array` as you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Using Arrays from [ouzo-goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies):

```
$result = Arrays::any($array, function($element) {
    return $element->id == 5;
});
```

Comment: This wrapper is an overkill here.

Comment: This wrapper expresses intentions better. IMHO it's more readable than "array_filter(...) - ok filtering, oh and then if resultant array is not empty than result is true". But it's a mater of taste.